# Fetching data from MySql and showing events in calendar

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I am using Adam Shaw's Full Calendar plugin as in my web-application.
I am new to json and its usability.
I want to fetch events from my database and display it into this calendar which I am not able to do it.
Please help me with this or if any link suggestion.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look for existing php applications using fullcalendar, keeping in mind that the new version is v2 and most applications will be implemented in v1.

Also, in the download of fullcalendar, there is a demo folder with an example php script.

In terms of json, I think you need to look for a good php and json tutorial. I am working in Ruby on Rails so cannot help you much with this, but maybe these comments will point you in the right direction.